# Parse dot com destroy all userdata from parse database

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

I want to set up my custom code in cloud code of parse.

```
Parse.Cloud.job("deleteUser", function(request, status) {    
    const query = new Parse.Query("SegmentData");
    query.equalTo("userID", request.userID);
    query.find()
    .then(Parse.Object.destroyAll)
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Error finding related comments " + error.code + ": " + error.message);
    });
    const query2 = new Parse.Query("ShowData");
    query.equalTo("userID", request.userID);
    query.find()
    .then(Parse.Object.destroyAll)
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Error finding related comments " + error.code + ": " + error.message);
    });
});
```

This is the code I have written so far. I want to destroy all the users that have username. They can be even more than 1000. Will this work if the users have more than 1000 records or do I have to amend my code?

Comment: This should delete the User entries, but not any records associated with those Users

Comment: I want to delete the data from 2 other tables with this username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the parse-server the limit of each query is 100 you need to set to

```
query.limit(1000);
```

If you want to have 1000 users maximum

You can see here how parse-server test and set the limit of each query:

- https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/master/spec/ParseAPI.spec.js#L314
- https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/master/src/Routers/ClassesRouter.js#L29